# Search over hundred thousand Redis keys in the most effective way

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

We are using StackExchange redis and have code that looks like this.

```
// get the target server
var server = conn.GetServer(someServer);

// show all keys in database 0 that include "foo" in their name
foreach(var key in server.Keys(pattern: "*foo*")) {
    Console.WriteLine(key);
}
```

The search will return over 100k keys.  These will then be processed and data for each key retrieved to create the end result.

I read somewhere that this might not be the most effective for such high number of keys as we have over 200k keys that we don't need to pull so that is the reason for the pattern.

Question is what/how can I retrieve process keys matching my pattern will not effecting other services that are using the redis server as our application relies heavily on redis.

Is there are way of getting keys in batches?

Or is 100k a quick sarch to do in redis?

Comment: Why the downvote?  I have provided sufficient details about what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of options here.  With regular Redis you can look at the `SCAN` command that will return batches of keys and not tie up the Redis server like the `KEYS` command can.  You then use a cursor based approach to iterate over the matches.  I'm not too familiar with the StackExchange client implementation - it may already be doing that for you in the background.  One way you could find out is to run your code while running the `MONITOR` command in the redis-cli, but don't do that on a production instance as it can be a bit of a performance hit to report all commands run through `MONITOR`.

If you're able to use Redis Stack, this will give you secondary indexing and search functionality if you are storing data in Redis Hashes or JSON documents (Redis Stack also adds JSON as a native data type).

With this functionality you'd use the `FT.CREATE` command to create one or more indices over keys that hold hashes or JSON documents.  You can then use the `FT.SEARCH` command to make more SQL like queries over these, and paginate through the result set.

Note that the Stack extensions to Redis are licensed differently than core Redis, so review this to see if it works for your use case: https://redis.com/legal/licenses/

Some resources that might be useful.. the RU102N course at Redis University will teach you about using StackExchange and other .NET Redis clients:

https://university.redis.com/courses/ru102n/

The RU203 and RU204 courses cover searching and JSON documents:

https://university.redis.com/courses/ru203/

https://university.redis.com/courses/ru204/

Disclosure: I work in Developer Relations at Redis and maintain the above courses.

Comment: So if the StackExchange does implement this then my result will be in batches?  Also you mentioned it would not tie up the production server much so might worth a shot.  I will check this first.  Appreciate the response.